# How to handle unknown multiple/single result with php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I just thought about this case and how to do it a bit more "professional". Does not seem to as if this the way to go even though I do not know any other. Somebody?!

```
$query = "SELECT col1 FROM ".PREFIX."table WHERE (col2 = :something)";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":something", $something, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bindColumn(1, $col1, PDO::PARAM_STR);

/* get number of rows */
$num_rows = $dbh->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();

if($num_rows == 1) {

  $stmt->fetch();
  $result = $col1;

} else {

  while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $result[] = $col1;
  }

}
```

Comment: Why not always put it in `$result[]` regardless of the number of rows.

Comment: Same as @slapyo . Generally if I know there will always be only 1 result I put it in a 'classic' variable, when it can return several rows it's in an array.

Comment: Per slapyo, why not always use the array? What is different about a single result compared to multiple results (or zero results)? You can handle all of those cases with a loop further on in your code, giving you more concise code with fewer opportunities to introduce bugs. The only time I would put a query result in a standard variable is if it is guaranteed to only return a single record (aggregate function with no group by), every other time I favour loops.